# Нужно посчитать сколько раз слово встречается в строке, но почему то выводит 0

Tags: c++, массивы, указатели

Ввести строку и слово. Определить сколько раз слово встречается в строке.

```
 #include "iostream"
 #include "string.h"
 #include "cstring"
 #include "conio.h"
 using namespace std;

int main() {
    int n = 0;
    char sent[100];
    cin.getline(sent, 100);
    char word[20];
    cin.getline(word, 20);
    char* tmp = word;
    while ((tmp = strstr(tmp, sent)) != NULL)
    {
        n++;
        tmp++;
    }
    cout << n;
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Надо поменять местами строку и слово:

```
char* tmp = sent;
while ((tmp = strstr(tmp, word)) != NULL)
```